# 2 way udp broadcast problem, borland turbo C++

Tags: c++, client, udp, broadcasting

i am trying to do a 2 way broadcast system on 2 computers. Its my first time doing network programming and in c++. lets say i have computer A and computer B, 2 sockets declared each, sockets sd and sd1 on each computer and client,server declaration on each computer. on computer A, socket sd on computer A is binded to client IP of 192.168.2.100:50000 on computer A. Then it receives information from broadcasting computer B using:

```
recvfrom(sd, (char *)received_buffer, 100, 0, NULL, 0)
```

on computer B, socket sd is set for broadcast using:

```
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&broadcastpermission, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

but sd is not binded because of broadcasting usage. computer B then broadcasts info to computer A using :

```
sendto(sd, (char *)send_buffer, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

where the declared server on computer B is of IP 192.168.2.100:50000 (same as client's IP on computer A so that it broadcasts to that IP).

This above methods works fine when computer B broadcasts to computer A. However, when I tried to do the same in reverse, Computer A broadcasts to computer B, it does not work. on computer A, socket sd1 is declared and set for broadcast using:

```
setsockopt(sd1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&broadcastpermission, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

and sd1 is not binded and computer A broadcasts to computer B using:

```
sendto(sd1, (char *)send_buffer, 100, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

where server is declared as IP 192.168.2.2:40000 (its the client IP address of computer B so that it broadcasts there). on computer B,socket sd1 is declared and binded to client and IP obtained automatically at IP 192.168.2.2:40000. Computer B receives the broadcast using:

```
recvfrom(sd, (char *)received_buffer, 100, 0, NULL, 0)
```

My apolgies for the very long story, but i need to be as clear as possible. Could anyone tell any posibility of why computer B can't receive broadcasts from computer A?

Comment: Did you check any return value? The setsockopt(...BROADCAST) may fail. I would try to avoid broadcasts at all if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are describing is that one way of communication works, but not the other. This is most often not related to issues in the code, but to configuration of the network, most often firewalls.

Using a sniffer (like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) verify that computer B receives the broadcast UDP datagrams from computer A. If this is not the case, verify the computer A is sending correct UDP datagrams. If A is sending but B is not receiving, there is a network issue (router, firewall, etc.). If B is receiving, but your application is not, verify that the port numbers are correct. You can use [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) (with `-a -n`) on computer B to see if you have the UDP socket open on the right port.

If all this doesn't get you closer, try to run exactly the same program on both computers - meaning don't swap the `sd` and `sd1` roles. Rather, run the same program (and same binary, if possible) on both computers, verifying with a sniffer that the datagrams are received correctly. Then you can see if the programs can receive each other. If this is the case, then there might be some over-sight in program B code that causes it to malfunction.

Finally, use `ping` to verify basic two way communication, by pinging each computer from the other one (note that `ping` doesn't confirm a valid two-way path - firewalls often block incoming echo requests, but not replies). Then use regular (non-broadcast) UDP sockets to verify UDP communication. It might be that unicast is allowed, but broadcast is not.